# getting elements types from xml document in xquery

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have the following xml document, I need an xquery expression to know how many element types are there in the document

```
    <category>
    <CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
  <book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
 </book>

 </category>
```

So the returned values I need to get from the query are `cd and book`. any one can help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XQuery (or XPath 2.0) `distinct-values(/category/*/local-name())` should suffice, the result is a sequence of string values `CD, book`.